# Row count and column count not showing correctly in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I am trying to select all rows and columns so that i can apply Pivot. There are 12327 rows in all and 7 columns. But LastRow2 and LastCol2 both display row count value ie 12327 but actual count of column is only 7.

```
With Sheet2
    LastRow2= .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol2= .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  Set PRange2= .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow2, LastCol2))
End With

MsgBox LastCol2 & " " & LastRow2
```

This is second pivot in my table, this code shows correct values in first pivot table code.

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code from your module? If not, there may be a typo. Did you check cell `RFC1` to ensure it is empty?

Comment: I did copy the code and assigned new reference table. Row no is showing correct value but column value is also coming same.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided.  Where did you **assign new reference table** in the code?  Is that `PRange2`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above code

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code. Are you sure **Sheet2** is the sheet you need to look at? `Sheet2` is not necessarily the name you see

Comment: You may have inadvertently written something in `Sheet2.Cells(1, 12327)` during testing. Check that cell's value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few possible traps:

- The documentation of Range.End is not very good. It tells you, it gives the same result as some keyboard combination - that is far from a clear definition. That's why I really try to avoid Range.End altogether and use Find instead (inside some udf).
- Since it is not clearly documented, it may very well have a different definition of "last" and of "empty". Let me be more clear:

  - If your range is more than one column, whose last row will it pick?
  - If your cell had changes in formatting, do you consider it empty? Does Range.End treat it the same way?

Hope this helps. I'm not allowed to comment, just to answer, to that's what I had to do ;)

Best,

YeOldHinnerk